# Can't open file 'main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python

I'm trying to trying to install and use HATCH using this: https://github.com/FlorianBord2/Hatch-python3-optimised

I've downloaded the requirements and the git clone, but whenever i try to run the program in cmd, i get this error message:

```
Python38-32\python.exe: can't open file 'main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any help at all would be appreciated!

Comment: are you in the working directory of the project with the console?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are in the same directory where the git repo is downloaded
2. If you are not working in a virtual environment then make sure the setup.py file of each has been set up successfully to check for installed requirement type in cmd/terminal `pip3 freeze`

   If you don't see anything that means your requirements are cached but not installed try writing the `pip install " again and check for setup.py starting to be installed or not.
3. If you are working in a virtual environment then make sure the env is activated and setup.py twice as for one-time cache file might be running which is not taken by your virtual environment
4. If you are not working using some text editor or IDE then only do all the above step mentioned